# free(): invalid next size (fast) in Cpp

Tags: c++, debugging, valgrind, free, delete-operator

I get the following error when I try to compile the code below and I don't know why.. I try to delete an object and an array at the end, but when I do it gives me the above error (without those 2 lines it runs and works perfectly fine!). Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include "PascalsTriangle.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct error1 {};
struct error2 {};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

        int n;

        try {
            istringstream ss1(argv[1]);
            if (!(ss1 >> n) || n<0) throw error1();
        }

        catch (...) {
            cout << argv[1] << " - error1" << endl;
            return 0;
        }

        PascalsTriangle* line = new PascalsTriangle(n);

        int* array = line->getTriangle();


        for(int i = 2; i < argc; i++)
        {
            int l;
            try
            {
        istringstream ss2(argv[i]);

        if (!(ss2 >> l)) throw error1();
        if(l < 0 || l > n) throw error2();
            }

            catch(error1&) {
                cout << argv[i] << " - error1" << endl;
                continue;
            }

            catch(error2&) {
                cout << argv[i] << " - error2" << endl;
                continue;
            }

            cout << l << " - " << array[l] << endl;
        }

    delete[] array;
    delete line;
        return 0;
}
```

the error:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x000000000162b040 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x80a46)[0x7f464d5d0a46]
./a.out[0x40149e]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f464d571ea5]
./a.out[0x400ed9]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 530557                             /home/dev/Desktop/lista2/c/a.out
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 08:05 530557                             /home/dev/Desktop/lista2/c/a.out
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 08:05 530557                             /home/dev/Desktop/lista2/c/a.out
0162b000-0164c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f464d24b000-7f464d34e000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 786957                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7f464d34e000-7f464d54e000 ---p 00103000 08:05 786957                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7f464d54e000-7f464d54f000 r--p 00103000 08:05 786957                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7f464d54f000-7f464d550000 rw-p 00104000 08:05 786957                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
7f464d550000-7f464d70f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 786960                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f464d70f000-7f464d90e000 ---p 001bf000 08:05 786960                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f464d90e000-7f464d912000 r--p 001be000 08:05 786960                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f464d912000-7f464d914000 rw-p 001c2000 08:05 786960                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f464d914000-7f464d919000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f464d919000-7f464d92d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 784625                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f464d92d000-7f464db2d000 ---p 00014000 08:05 784625                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f464db2d000-7f464db2e000 r--p 00014000 08:05 784625                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f464db2e000-7f464db2f000 rw-p 00015000 08:05 784625                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f464db2f000-7f464dc14000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 400616                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7f464dc14000-7f464de13000 ---p 000e5000 08:05 400616                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7f464de13000-7f464de1b000 r--p 000e4000 08:05 400616                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7f464de1b000-7f464de1d000 rw-p 000ec000 08:05 400616                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
7f464de1d000-7f464de32000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f464de32000-7f464de55000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 784516                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7f464e036000-7f464e03b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f464e050000-7f464e054000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f464e054000-7f464e055000 r--p 00022000 08:05 784516                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7f464e055000-7f464e057000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 784516                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7ffff88fc000-7ffff891d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffff89fe000-7ffff8a00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Valgrind with --leak-check=full

```
==30110== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==30110== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==30110== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==30110== Command: ./a.out 5 4
==30110== 
--30110-- Valgrind options:
--30110--    --suppressions=/usr/lib/valgrind/debian-libc6-dbg.supp
--30110--    --leak-check=full
--30110--    -v
--30110-- Contents of /proc/version:
--30110--   Linux version 3.8.0-31-generic (buildd@panlong) (gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1) ) #46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:03:44 UTC 2013
--30110-- Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, amd64-sse3-cx16-avx
--30110-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 4096
--30110-- Valgrind library directory: /usr/lib/valgrind
--30110-- Reading syms from /home/dev/Desktop/lista2/c/a.out
--30110-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
--30110--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 5d246d73 wanted cbf42dbe)
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC is valid
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC is valid
--30110-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux ..
--30110--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 8dadd6e3 wanted 096f8488)
--30110--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--30110--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--30110-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--30110-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/debian-libc6-dbg.supp
--30110-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
==30110== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-30110-by-dev-on-???
==30110== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-30110-by-dev-on-???
==30110== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-30110-by-dev-on-???
==30110== 
==30110== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==30110== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==30110== or are doing some strange experiment):
==30110==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=30110 ...command...
==30110== 
==30110== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==30110==   /path/to/gdb ./a.out
==30110== and then give GDB the following command
==30110==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=30110
==30110== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==30110== 
--30110-- REDIR: 0x4018f40 (strlen) redirected to 0x3806c7e1 (???)
--30110-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 7ae7d82a wanted 34ea3d89)
--30110--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--30110-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 272279e5 wanted bc83f658)
--30110--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--30110-- REDIR: 0x4018db0 (index) redirected to 0x4c2d440 (index)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x4018e30 (strcmp) redirected to 0x4c2e480 (strcmp)
--30110-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.17 ..
--30110--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 397a007e wanted 2d914133)
--30110--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--30110-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
--30110--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 ..
--30110--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 3e210681 wanted d01e18f4)
--30110--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--30110-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
--30110--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 08d04634 wanted e58fe8a7)
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC is valid
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC is valid
--30110-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so
--30110--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 0f18ff95 wanted 109dbed1)
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC is valid
--30110--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.17.so ..
--30110--   .. CRC is valid
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53daa30 (strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d6dc0 (strnlen) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53dcd00 (strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d9840 (memset) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d97f0 (memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d87b0 (__GI_strrchr) redirected to 0x4c2d260 (__GI_strrchr)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d6ce0 (__GI_strlen) redirected to 0x4c2d7c0 (__GI_strlen)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d51a0 (strcmp) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x54867c0 (__strcmp_sse42) redirected to 0x4c2e3e0 (strcmp)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d6c90 (strlen) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x54b72f0 (__strlen_sse2_pminub) redirected to 0x4c2d7a0 (strlen)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x4e93650 (operator new(unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c2c740 (operator new(unsigned long))
--30110-- REDIR: 0x4e91950 (operator delete(void*)) redirected to 0x4c2b530 (operator delete(void*))
--30110-- REDIR: 0x4e93760 (operator new[](unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c2bfd0 (operator new[](unsigned long))
==30110== Invalid write of size 4
==30110==    at 0x401110: PascalsTriangle::PascalsTriangle(int) (PascalsTriangle.cpp:42)
==30110==    by 0x4012D4: main (main.cpp:27)
==30110==  Address 0x5a1b164 is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==30110==    at 0x4C2C037: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30110==    by 0x4010D8:PascalsTriangle::PascalsTriangle(int) (WierszTrojkataPascala.cpp:39)
==30110==    by 0x4012D4: main (main.cpp:27)
==30110== 
--30110-- REDIR: 0x4e91980 (operator delete[](void*)) redirected to 0x4c2afb0 (operator delete[](void*))
==30110== Invalid write of size 4
==30110==    at 0x401146: PascalsTriangle::PascalsTriangle(int) (PascalsTriangle.cpp:45)
==30110==    by 0x4012D4: main (main.cpp:27)
==30110==  Address 0x5a1b164 is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==30110==    at 0x4C2C037: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30110==    by 0x4010D8: PascalsTriangle::PascalsTriangle(int) (PascalsTriangle.cpp:39)
==30110==    by 0x4012D4: main (main.cpp:27)
==30110== 
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53df3e0 (memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x549c6b0 (__memcpy_ssse3_back) redirected to 0x4c2e7b0 (memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d9200 (bcmp) redirected to 0x4a25710 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--30110-- REDIR: 0x54b1c20 (__memcmp_sse4_1) redirected to 0x4c2f570 (bcmp)
4 - 5
--30110-- REDIR: 0x53d09b0 (free) redirected to 0x4c2ba00 (free)
==30110== 
==30110== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30110==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30110==   total heap usage: 11 allocs, 11 frees, 260 bytes allocated
==30110== 
==30110== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30110== 
==30110== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
==30110== 
==30110== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==30110== Invalid write of size 4
==30110==    at 0x401146: PascalsTriangle::PascalsTriangle(int) (PascalsTriangle.cpp:45)
==30110==    by 0x4012D4: main (main.cpp:27)
==30110==  Address 0x5a1b164 is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==30110==    at 0x4C2C037: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30110==    by 0x4010D8: WierszTrojkataPascala::WierszTrojkataPascala(int) (WierszTrojkataPascala.cpp:39)
==30110==    by 0x4012D4: main (main.cpp:27)
==30110== 
==30110== 
==30110== 1 errors in context 2 of 2:
==30110== Invalid write of size 4
==30110==    at 0x401110: PascalsTriangle::PascalsTriangle(int) (PascalsTriangle.cpp:42)
==30110==    by 0x4012D4: main (main.cpp:27)
==30110==  Address 0x5a1b164 is 0 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==30110==    at 0x4C2C037: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==30110==    by 0x4010D8: PascalsTriangle::PascalsTriangle(int) (PascalsTriangle.cpp:39)
==30110==    by 0x4012D4: main (main.cpp:27)
==30110== 
--30110-- 
--30110-- used_suppression:      2 dl-hack3-cond-1
==30110== 
==30110== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

PascalsTriangle class:

```
#include "PascalsTriangle.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int lineNr;
int* triangle;

int PascalsTriangle::coeff(int m)
{
        int n=lineNr;
        int* aux= new int[n+1];

        aux[0]=1;

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            aux[i]=1;
            for(int l=i-1; l>0; l--)
            {
                aux[l]=aux[l]+aux[l-1];
            }
        }

    int coeff=aux[m];
    delete [] aux;
        return coeff;
}


int* PascalsTriangle::getTrangle() {return triangle;}

PascalsTriangle::PascalsTriangle(int n)
{
        triangle=new int[n];
        lineNr=n;

        triangle[0] = 1; triangle[n] = 1;

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                triangle[i] = coeff(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to forget that indexing of arrays, allocated like arrays or from the heap with `new`, are indexed from zero to size minus one.

In the `PascalsTriangle` constructor you have a loop from one `n` (inclusive) but the index of `triangle` is from zero to `n - 1`.

You have the same misunderstanding in a loop in `PascalsTriangle::coeff` as well.

---

By having aloop from `1` to `n` (inclusive) you *overwrite* the allocated memory, and writing beyond allocated memory leads to *undefined behavior*. In this case it seems that you have a memory allocator which checks for overwrites like these, and adds a special value beyond the memory you allocate. If that value is not correct when calling `delete` (which calls `free`) you will get a runtime error.